# Do I have to lock to check a work-available flag used with a condition variable before setting it, and if so why?

Tags: c++, concurrency, thread-safety, condition-variable

I have a worker thread in a thread pool that behaves like so:

```
while (running)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_condition.wait(lock, [&] { return m_workAvailable; });
    m_workAvailable = false;
    lock.unlock();

    // (Perform work...)
}
```

When I drop work into this worker thread, it looks like so:

```
// (enqueue the actual work item...)

if (!m_workAvailable)
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
  m_workAvailable = true;
}

m_condition.notify_one();
```

After seeing the behavior of this code in practice I'm guessing that there is some kind of concurrency bug related to the

```
if(! m_workAvailable)
```

check here, which is meant to bypass contention for the mutex unless necessary.  But if this is so, I don't actually see the scenario that would cause this problem.

[ **Update**: I have tried this with`m_workAvailable` being both `bool` and `volatile bool`. I have not as yet tried `std::atomic<bool>`, though as far as I understand that wouldn't be fundamentally different from `volatile bool` here. ]

Questions:

1. Is this indeed a concurrency bug?
2. If so, why -- what does this allow to go wrong?
3. If so, is there any way of doing what I'm doing here that doesn't require me to lock the mutex every single time a piece of work comes in?

Comment: Is `m_workAvailable` an `atomic`? Is `running` an `atomic`? Are you releasing the `mutex` _before_ you've fetched the workload? It just says "_// Perform work_", but it doesn't say where it gets the work from.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. Access to the flag, ***and*** signaling the condition variable should be done while holding the mutex lock.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Signalling the condition variable doesn't need to hold the mutex (normally). I may miss something in the above scenario though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: `running` isn't giving me problems.  `m_workAvailable` is just a `bool`.  Yes, I release the mutex before fetching the work item.  The work is in a ring buffer, so it's being inserted in the next slot(s) while it's being read from the current one.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Well, I suspected that it might be a bug, but why is it a bug?

Comment: What type is `m_workAvailable`?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Ok, then see David's answer below. :) if `running` is also just a `bool` it can also cause you problems if you change it in one thread and read it in another. The same goes for the workload.

Comment: I'm afraid that a complete explanation of "why is it a bug" will be a small novel, since it will need to explain every detail of C++'s concurrency model. The rule of thumb is: if something is accessed while locking a mutex, somewhere, then this mutex needs to always be locked when accessing it. The shown code locks the mutex when it sets the flag, but doesn't lock the mutex when it's checking the same flag. The End.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this indeed a concurrency bug?

Yes.

> If so, why -- what does this allow to go wrong?

It's undefined behavior. The standards don't say what happens if a non-atomic type is accessed by one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it. Your code does that. So it can break in any imaginable way.

> If so, is there any way of doing what I'm doing here that doesn't require me to lock the mutex every single time a piece of work comes in?

Yes, Do this:

```
{
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
     m_workAvailable = true;
     m_condition.notify_one();
}
```

Your platform, if it has a good implementation, will detect that the mutex is already held when you call `notify_one` and avoid synchronizing again. The net effect will be roughly the same as not acquiring the mutex during the set of `m_workAvailable` if the mutex isn't contended. (If it is contended, the cost is unavoidable anyway.)

> I have not as yet tried `std::atomic<bool>`, though as far as I understand that wouldn't be fundamentally different from `volatile bool` here.

Umm, huh? What threading standard defines the behavior when a `volatile bool` is accessed in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it? I don't know of any except Microsoft Visual Studio. By contrast, `std::atomic<bool>` has well-defined semantics in that case.

Comment: Is this under the assumption that I'm holding a lock on the mutex while I'm doing the work?  I'm using a ring buffer so that I can read and write items of work simultaneously.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You should hold the mutex any time you access shared state. If you're holding the lock long enough that contention on it becomes an issue, you should fix that. You need the lock to manipulate the buffer anyway, so it's hard to see how having to hold it while setting a single `bool` to `true` adds any cost/complexity. (How can you enqueue the work item without holding the lock that protects the queue?)

Comment: I shouldn't need the lock in order to write data to buffer[1987] at the same time I'm reading data from buffer[1986], right?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You may or may not, depending on circumstances. There are two issues: 1) You writing to `buffer[1987]` and then another thread reading from `buffer[1987]` without any synchronization. 2) Possible race conditions with the offsets or pointers. My gut tells me you are making this much harder than it needs to be. Did you try just using a mutex and condition variable the normal, simple way? Are you sure there's a real performance issue?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Take a look at lock free ring buffers if you don't want to hold a lock. I think most of them use `atomic`s to accomplish that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo; I'm using a lock-free ring buffer to hold the work items; the mutex is just there to use with the condition variable so that I can wake up a thread when work is available.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Is the lock-free ring buffer thread safe? Is it an implementation we can read about somewhere?